# Assigning values from a static char array to a dynamically allocated char array

Tags: c, dynamic, static, memcpy, strcpy

Today I was told that I would be able to easily take the contents of a static array and copy the data over to the dynamically allocated one. I searched for a long while and still have not found a good explanation as to how and why that is possible.
For example, if I have code as follows,

```
int i = 0;
char array[64];
for (; i < 64; ++i)
{
  array[i] = "a";
}

char* dynamicArray = (char*) malloc (sizeof (char*) * strlen (array));
```

I was told that I could take the contents of array, which in this case is an array of a's, and copy that data to my dynamic array. I am still confused as to how I can even do that, since functions like memcpy and strcpy have not been working with the static array. Is this copying situation possible?
Thank you for the help, and I hope my explanation was okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has a few issues:

```
array[i] = "a";
```

tries to assign a string (an array of characters) to a single `char`.  You should use `'a'` to define a single character.

```
char* dynamicArray = (char*) malloc (sizeof (char*) * strlen (array));
```

allocates memory but doesn't assign it.  `strlen(array)` is also unsafe; `strlen` counts the number of characters until a nul terminator but `array` doesn't have one.

Your code should look something like

```
int i = 0;
char array[64];
for (; i < 63; ++i) {
  array[i] = 'a';
}
array[63] = '\0';
char* dynamicArray = malloc (strlen(array)+1); // +1 for nul terminator
strcpy(dynamicArray, array); // copy contents of array into dynamicArray
// use array
free(dynamicArray); // must have exactly one call to free for each call to malloc
```

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining it along with comments. This helped a lot. Another question: if I were to use this method of copying in a function, then using it to insert the copied data into a list, is there a way to free the memory after insertion without loosing the inserted data?